# Alternate optimal can be unbounded

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

Can it happen that at the optimal simplex table for a maximization problme, we have reduced cost of one of the nonbasic variable as 0, but no entry in its corresponding column at the optimum is positive meaning no basic variable can leave, thereby implying unboundedness. But how can this be since we are already at an optimal table?

Comment: I've left a comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4623057/how-to-apply-complementary-slackness#comment9751579_4623057).

Comment: Nice comment by the way

Comment: What you have done then? Nothing: No reply, no clarifucatuon about the new problem, no accpting any answer. Nice behaviour.

Comment: I asked a question to which i did not receive any answer after you answered initially

Comment: First of all, I asked you for more information. Secondly, you should open a new thread for another problem.  Btw, I've answered your additional question about the original question in the comments.